# Hibernate configuration for MongoDB loadbalancing

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate, database-replication, hibernate-ogm

I have got a small mongoDB cluster with 3 nodes (no sharding, only replication). Now the insertion to the primary node is propogating the new data to the secondary node as expected (basic replication). I am using java and hibernate.

Now what I want is to loadbalance the read requests among the whole replica set instead of primary node always being used to serve the data. Is there some way that I tell hibernate (through query string) about the available servers and somehow hibernate distributes the request (either randomly or in a systematic manner)? What would be the right way to achieve load balancing?

Answer (score 1):

**The setting you are looking for is called read-preference.** If you take a look at the [doc here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/ogm/4.1/reference/en-US/html/ogm-mongodb.html#_mongodb_specific_configuration_properties), you will find:

> **hibernate.ogm.mongodb.read_preference**
>
> **Specifies the ReadPreference to be applied when issuing reads against the MongoDB datastore.** Possible settings are (values of the
> ReadPreferenceType enum): PRIMARY, PRIMARY_PREFERRED, SECONDARY,
> **SECONDARY_PREFERRED** and NEAREST.

What you would probably use in this case is SECONDARY_PREFERRED, which effectively means that read operation will by default routed to slave nodes, but hibernate will fall back to primary if that is the only available node left.

Comment: Looks promising, gonna give it a try. Any idea how I could log the hostname for hibernate read operation? Just wanted to cross confirm that setting this property is actually reading the data from the secondary node.

Comment: You can temporarily enable trace log on org.hibernate . It is a bit verbose, but does the job.

Comment: What is missing here is that depending on the write concern reads from the secondaries do not necessarily return the same data as a read from a primary would. Replication only provides eventual consistency.